# Temporary nosepad for eyeglasses

Tags: eyeglasses

While cleaning my eye glass, one of the nose pad fell off my eye glasses and went down the drain through the sink.

Currently, no nosepad is available for delivery where I live. Also I would prefer not to go to any eyeglasses store, as they are all all pretty far off and really crowded, which is quite risky now due to Covid.

What can I use in place of a nosepad? I need to wear eyeglasses the entire day, and without the nosepad, it's both uncomfortable and causes redness on my nose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First clean the area with rubbing alcohol. Then cut small squares from a bandaid. Use the cloth-type bandaid. Place a few layers if needed, and press each one firmly into place.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get a plastic bag and cut a small piece off it. Apply a small blob of silicone sealant to the bag (about the side of an eyeglasses nose pad, then pick it up and carefully apply it to the glasses (perhaps hold them in a vise, or stick them into something, like a potato, so that they don't roll around and are fixed in such a position that the bag/silicone is resting in place

Wait for the silicone to cure, then peel the bag off it, perhaps with the aid of a scalpel. You should be able to replicate a resting pad, and if you can get the silicone to wrap around the peg that sticks out of the glasses, it will be quite secure.

Elmy was concerned in the comments that the silicone might stick too well to the frame. If you feel this could be the case for your frame you could consider the alternative approach of finding some fine wire, making a sort of drawing pin shape with it - a few turns of wire in a circle and two wire legs sticking out, then embed the wire in a small dab of silicone (with the legs protruding), wait for the silicone to cure and then attached your lifehacked pressure pad to your glasses frame using the bendable metal legs. Because the silicone is already cured it wont stick to the frame, and retention will be via the legs, bent/tied appropriately and cut to size.

Comment: This idea is quite nice, but how is OP going to remove the DIY silicone pad once they get a replacement nose pad? In my experience silicone sticks too well to everything to be removed cleanly. That would make the whole frame unusable.

Comment: I've a doubt that the silicone will stick so well to the smooth metal frame that it will be impossible to remove ; if it was that good, a plumber would never be able to remove the old silicone when re-sealing a shower. The contact point for this silicone pad will be tiny (I'm not advocating coating the whole frame with it; just getting a bit of silicone squeezed through the small hole through which the pressure pad normally sits) and wont resist determined pulling. Fitting a new pad simply by pulling the silicone off, and pushing a new pad through the hole will displace any existing silicone

Comment: (But i you're concerned about this then others may be concerned, so I added a suggestion to the answer which may help with this)

Answer (score 0):

I used a Q-tip cotton swab. I cut the cotton to the exact thickness of the nose pads. I took the cotton disk and applied 1 tiny drop of super glue to  bottomside and stuck it on the metal piece that held the old nose pad and wallah. Lasted 6 months. They would have lasted longer if needed. Comfortable,  since the cotton is nice and soft.

Answer (score 0):

I used a cloth bandage with the ends cut off and wrapped around the nose piece. No glue needed.